# Why can't Node-RED parse the VCAP_SERVICES environment in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am using Node-RED and want to parse in Bluemix `VCAP_SERVICES` but I am getting an error.  My code is:

```
var services = context.global.VCAP_SERVICES;
var env_cloudint = services['CloudIntegration'][0].credentials;
```

but I get this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CloudIntegration' of undefined
```

I do have CloudIntegration in my `VCAP_SERVICES`.  Do I need anything extra in my code to exploit `VCAP_SERVICES`?

Comment: Your error indicates that 'services' itself is undefined, not that the item 'CloudIntegration' in the 'services' array is undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, environment variables are not added to the Function global context object.  To access the Bluemix `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable from a Node-RED flow, you will need to add it to the Function node's global context.

Edit **bluemix-settings.js** and add an entry to the functionGlobalContext property:

```
functionGlobalContext: { VCAP_SERVICES: JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES)}
```

Then redeploy your app. When redeployed, you can then access `VCAP_SERVICES` in a Function node as the `context.global.VCAP_SERVICES` variable.